# NGRX Entity addOne replaces object in current state

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I am trying to perform insert operation and I am following this article
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ngrx-entity-feature-modules-tutorial/

Unfortunately instead of adding new object to current state previous one is replaced by new one. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Gif above present behavior of actual code.

action file:

```
export enum BookingActionTypes {
    TicketAdded = '[Booking API] Ticket Added' 
}

export class TicketAdded implements Action {
    readonly type = BookingActionTypes.TicketAdded;
    constructor(public payload: {orderedTicket: OrderedTicket}) { }
}

export type BookingActions = TicketAdded;
```

reducer file:

```
export interface BookingState extends EntityState<OrderedTicket> { }

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<OrderedTicket> = createEntityAdapter<OrderedTicket>();

export const initialBookingState: BookingState = adapter.getInitialState();

export function bookingReducer(state = initialBookingState, action: BookingActions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BookingActionTypes.TicketAdded:
            return adapter.addOne(action.payload.orderedTicket, state);

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that is correct. You are in diff tab so it will only show the different between current state and previous state

Answer (score 0):

**This Should work For you...**
**I have updated your reducer....**

```
export function bookingReducer(state = initialBookingState, action: BookingActions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BookingActionTypes.TicketAdded:{
            return {
                ...state, {...adapter.addOne, ...action.payload.orderedTicket}
                // this will work like 
                // var test = {data: 1}
                // var test2 = {test: 2}
                // {...test, ...test2} = {data:1,test:2 }
            }
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```